# Group XML file based on a given number using XSLT

Tags: xml, formatting, grouping, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to group a XML file based on a XML tag value. Below is my input XML.

```xml
<Root>
    <GroupNumber>3</GroupNumber>
    <EDICustomer>
        <Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
    </EDICustomer>
</Root>
```

I don't know how many EDICustomerLine tags will be there. If GroupNumber value is greater than the number of EDICustomerLine tags leave the EDICustomer child tags as it is but if the GroupNumber is less than EDICustomerLine tags we have to split the EDICustomerLine tags based on the GroupNumber tag value. So in this scenario the expected XML will be like following.

```xml
<Root>
    <EDICustomer>
        <Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
    </EDICustomer>
    <EDICustomer>
        <Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
    </EDICustomer>
</Root>
```

First EDICustomer parent tag contains Company, Customer, CreationDate, CreationTime and 3  based on the Group number value. Like that 2nd EDICustomer should contain 3 or less  tags. We don't know how many EDICustomerLine tags and the value of Group Number will be there. Also

```xml
<Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
```

This above part should repeat in all the EDICustomer groups (This part will be possible if we find a way to loop EDICustomerLine based on group number).

First of all I want to know whether this scenario is possible in XSLT.
If possible, can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with the following XSLT-2.0 stylesheet. It groups the `<EDICustomerLine>` elements in groups of `GroupNumber` and then iterates over the `current-group()`. The constant part is created by the first `xsl:copy-of`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  

   <xsl:template match="Root">
     <xsl:variable name="max" select="GroupNumber" />
     <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Handle the "zero-items" situation" -->
        <xsl:if test="count(EDICustomer/EDICustomerLine) = 0">
            <EDICustomer>
                <xsl:copy-of select="EDICustomer[1]/Company | EDICustomer[1]/Customer | EDICustomer[1]/CreationDate | EDICustomer[1]/CreationTime" />
            </EDICustomer>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="EDICustomer/EDICustomerLine" group-by="(position()-1) idiv $max">
            <EDICustomer>
                <!-- Add a <GroupNr> element with the index of the group -->
                <GroupNr><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></GroupNr>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Company | ../Customer | ../CreationDate | ../CreationTime" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </EDICustomer>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its result is:

```
<Root>
    <EDICustomer>
        <GroupNr>1</GroupNr>
        <Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
    </EDICustomer>
    <EDICustomer>
        <GroupNr>2</GroupNr>
        <Company>IWS</Company>
        <Customer>150</Customer>
        <CreationDate>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationDate>
        <CreationTime>2020-03-15T10:29:08.813</CreationTime>
        <EDICustomerLine>
            <Barcode>447896130245</Barcode>
            <ItemDescription>Medium</ItemDescription>
            <Warehouse>B01</Warehouse>
            <Status>12</Status>
        </EDICustomerLine>
    </EDICustomer>
</Root>
```

This is as desired.

Comment: Hi @zx485 Thanks very much for your answer it's working and you are a real hero :) But there is small issue. when I put 1 there it is not displaying as expected and all the line records are inside one EDICustomer tag. It's ok I can handle it by putting a if and check whether the GroupNumber is 1 or not and if 1 just generate EDICustomer  for each line tag. There's another thing How can I get that group number like first EDICustomer  tag is Group Number 1 second one is Group Number 2 like that.

Comment: I can get group number from position()

Comment: Hi @zx485 why is it not working for XML with 514 EDICustomerLine tags. Basically i'm dividing that 514 document as 50 tags per one group. So there should be 11 groups. But there is only 2 groups.

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon:  I apologize. The `group-by` expression of the `xsl:for-each-group` has been wrong. I fixed it now.

Comment: I didn't check it for larger line records earlier. Now it's working for larger like records. Thanks!!